# ! casts the expression to its underlying non-nullable type in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What does it mean when they say:

> A postfix exclamation mark (!) takes the expression on the left and casts it to its underlying non-nullable type.

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator

Does it mean that it checks whether the expression is null or not and then throws error before executing anything further?

Please explain this:

> casts it to its underlying non-nullable type

Comment: Its like an assertion. If the variable could be null, the compiler throws an error when you try to access its methods. By asserting that the variable will not be null, you fix the compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that it checks whether the expression is null or not and then throws error before executing anything further?

Yes, `!` will insert a null-check that will throw a `TypeError` if the expression turns out to be `null` at runtime.

As stated in the last paragraph of the ["Null assertion operator" section](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator):

> Of course, like any cast, using `!` comes with a loss of static safety. The cast must be checked at runtime to preserve soundness and it may fail and throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

`casts it to its underlying non-nullable type`
It means that the variable might be **`nullable`** but when you are explicitly sure that the current call to the variable will **not** return null then you use the `!` operator to imply that the variable is not null.

Answer (score 1):

For example you have this:

```
List<ChatMessage?> messages;
```

This would be a list of messages. But they can be null.
The message has a body, id etc.
If I would try to call an id on a message that is inside the list as followed:

```
message.id
```

Message can be null in this case which will tell me that Message cannot be Null when calling id.

So what we do here is a ! to the end of message then it casts to its underlying type which can't be a null at this point(because we define it cannot be with the !) or it will throw an error:

```
messages!.id
```